# Angular ngController without an element (and orderBy issue)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm experiencing a very strange problem. I need to generate a table with one TR per element of an array, so I use ngRepeat. Each TR must also have its own ngController.

This works, but ordering the array assigns somehow the wrong scope to each contoller

```
<table ng-controller="ArrayController">
    <tr ng-click="log()" ng-repeat="val in myArray | orderBy: 'value'"  ng-controller="MyController">
        <td>{{ val.value }}</td>
        <td>{{ val.value2 }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It must somehow get confused because ngRepeat and the contoller are on the same element. I guess one solution would be to add the the controller *within* the TR, but it can only contain, of course, TDs, and since there are two of the, I would need to nest them within a single element.

How to solve this problem? Is mine a known issue?

Thanks

**EDIT**:

This was my fault. What didn't work was deleting the items. Since i tried to remove an element form the array (myArray in in the example) with splice and $index, I ended up removing the wrong indexed element (because of the sort).

Comment: this is of course a mock-up example from the real project. forcing orderByFilter on the controller (script-side) makes it work, though

Comment: you're aware that each row will use it's own instance of the controller the way you have it set up?

Comment: sure, and I expect the $scope in each controller to reflect its row, but it seems like it's attached to the item BEFORE the sorting

Comment: suggest you prepare a demo that replicates problem. Hard for us to follow what your problem is

Comment: I tried this http://jsfiddle.net/A75Fe/3/ but here it works as expected!